# Changing the header Saleforce Logo in the visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I want to change the Header logo (Salesforce logo) with the custom Logo. I dont want to change the logo for the APP, but for particular visualforce pages i want to change. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with javascript . This is the example.
The header logo is an image with id **phHeaderLogoImage** . We can change them using javascript and it will be good to go.

[image]

Check the below code:

```
 <apex:page >
      <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
      <h1>Congratulations</h1>
      This is your new Page
      <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
      <script>
          window.onload = function() {
          var element=document.getElementById("phHeaderLogoImage");
        //  alert(element.src);
          element.src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/657703841085935616/EulXOwHD.png";
    };
      </script>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Welcome and Welcome once again to SFSE.

Answer (score 5):

Try with this code..

get the logo image element using javascript and change the src value

```
<apex:page >
    <script>
    document.getElementsByClassName('phHeaderCustomLogo')[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Not usually suggested that you reference automatically generated styles or elements (they can change at any time) but this is likely the only way to do it.